# Package biblatex Error

Tags: latex, bibtex

I have a latex document and wanted to add references using bibtex. I created a file and saved it with the extension .bib. In the latex file I use \usepackage{biblatex} and then 
\bibliographystyle{style}
\bibliography{PHcite}
When I compile I get this error:

./Physics IA.tex:153: Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.
See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.153 \bibliographystyle{style}

?

./Physics IA.tex:154: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.154 \bibliography
                   {PHcite}

Comment: update: I'm using \bibliographystyle{unsrt}, same appears in the errors

Answer (score 2):

You just have to look at one of the [`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) [examples](//mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/) in order to see what the problem is:

Don't use

```
\documentclass[<options>]{<class>}
% ...
\begin{document}
% ...
\bibliographystyle{<style>}
\bibliography{<bib>}
% ...
\end{document}
```

Instead use

```
\documentclass[<options>]{<class>}
% ...
\usepackage[
  style = <style>,
  <other options>
]{biblatex}
% ...
\addbibresource[<options>]{<bib>.bib}
% ...
\begin{document}
% ...
\printbibliography[<options>]
% ...
\end{document}
```

Reference:

- [What to do to switch to `biblatex`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/5764)
- [What is the difference between BibTeX and `biblatex`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411/5764)